# Using FTP to deploy ASP.NET Core application on Azure web app

Tags: linux, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app running on a Linux app plan in Azure. To this I would like to deploy an ASP.NET Core 1.0 application using the FTP deployment option. I have configured my CI (AppVeyor) to do a dotnet publish and then upload the resulting files to the web app FTP. However, this process just uploads the files, how can start my application after the files have been uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

The website should start automatically on the first request. If it was running while you were deploying, it should detect the changes and restart.

Assuming you upload the correct files and the correct directory structure, there shouldn't be any extra work needed.

Comment: My CI server does a dotnet publish so I got all my application files and all of its dependencies in a folder. This is then uploaded to /site/wwwroot on the Azure side. The app is running but the changes doesn't seem to be picked up. What would be the correct files and directory structure?

Comment: Where are you uploading relative to the site's root?

Comment: I've used /site/wwwroot.So I guess /site is directly in the site's root.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that as of now, it is not possible to deploy ASP.NET Core apps to web apps running on Linux using FTP deployment.